# Complex numbers- modulus inequality problem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given that: $a^2>b^2+c^2$, $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$

I want to show that one of the modulus of the complex numbers:
$z_1=\frac{-ai+i\sqrt{a^2-b^2-c^2}}{(c+ib)}$ and $z_2=\frac{-ai-i\sqrt{a^2-b^2-c^2}}{(c+ib)}$ is less than 1 and the other is greater than 1.

My attempt:
I took $z_1$ and rationalized its denominator by multiplying it with $(c-ib)$ above and below and then simplyifying the term I took the modulus:

$$|z_1|=|\frac{b(\sqrt{a^2-b^2-c^2}-a)-ic(a+\sqrt{a^2-b^2+c^2})}{(b^2+c^2)}|$$

$$|z_1|=\sqrt{\frac{b^2.(2a^2-b^2-c^2-2a\sqrt{a^2-b^2-c^2})}{(b^2+c^2)^2}+\frac{c^2.(2a^2-b^2-c^2-2a\sqrt{a^2-b^2-c^2})}{(b^2+c^2)^2}}$$

but then I dont know how to proceed further. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z_1 \bar z_2=1$ so $|z_1||z_2|=1$, hence we either have the required result or $|z_1|=|z_2|=1$. But in the latter case, we have that $\bar z_1=1/z_1=\bar z_2$ so $z_1= z_2$ and that is manifestly not true since $a^2-b^2-c^2 >0$, so we are done!

Edit as per comments: since $z_1=u_1/v, z_2=u_2/v$ and for $a>0$ obviously $|u_2|>|u_1|$, it follows that $|z_1|<1, |z_2|>1$ if $a>0$ and the reverse if $a<0$

Comment: This is ingenious; but I needed which one would be less than 1 explicitly. The original question was about a contour integration. So the given $z_i$ are the roots and to find the residue, I want to know which of the $z_i$ would lie inside my contour of unit circle.

Comment: it is obvious that $|z_2|>|z_1|$ if $a>0$ otherwise $|z_1|<|z_2|$; though note that the question doesn't ask that

Comment: You have mentioned $|z_1|<|z_2| $ in both cases..which one is true. Could you please explain in short how. i am not able to figure out. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: If $a>0$ then the numerator of $z_2$ is bigger in absolute value so $|z_2|>|z_1|$; if $a<0$ the reverse is true